# Why couldn't I get the source code line from addr2line?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I'm trying to get the line of source code from addr2line for the rasbian 5.4.y kernel.

My host environment is ubuntu18.04.2 on virtualbox, and I'm compiling the kernel with arm-linux-gnueabihf- cross-compiler.

I compiled the kernel with bcm2711_defconfig configuration since the target machine is Raspberry Pi 4, following the official guide, https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md, with 32-bit arm arch configuration. I didn't modify any kernel configuration at all.

I obtained the address of a function (_local_bh_enable here, for an instance) from vmlinux by using objdump as below,

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -x linux/vmlinux | grep _local_bh_enable
...
c0227a28 g     F .text  00000098 _local_bh_enable
```

As you can see above, I got the address for _local_bh_enable as 0xc0227a28.

Then I ran addr2line to get the line of the address but some strange result I've got as below.

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-addr2line -fe linux/vmlinux -a 0xc0227a28
0xc0227a28
_local_bh_enable
.tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o:?
```

I don't get what that means. Isn't it supposed to give the source file name with the line number on it?

I've also tried with many other functions but ended up all the same with the ".tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms2.o:?", not the code line I'm expecting to get.

Am I missing something here? Please give me any help for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the kernel configuration, and I've found out that the CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO was not set. It seems the cause.
I'm compiling the kernel with CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO set, let me see whether it's working.

Comment: I've confirmed that it worked after compiling the kernel with CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO. addr2line is working normal now.